# Renaming system folders from Grub command line - Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, grub2, grubrescue

I started learning basics of `linux (ubuntu)` file system and troubleshooting with `grub` . So i renamed the `/etc` folder to `/etc_xyz` on purpose and tried to restart which ,of course, stuck and i had to manually power off it . Now I started system again and got into `GRUB command line` . where when i did `ls` , it gave me system partitions like `hd0`, `hd0,gpt7` and so on . but i could not solve the mystery of renaming `/etc_xyz` to `/etc` again using that command line utility . can anyone help ? i checked the [GRUB Troubleshooting Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting) but couldn't make it .

Comment: If you don't get an answer on renaming "/etc_xyc" to "/etc" within grub you can boot with Try Ubuntu Live and rename it that way. I think it would be easier than grub anyway.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix yes dear i know . but i want to do it in grub command line way

Comment: please don't call me "dear" @ImranNaqvi. Your link is a grub summary for a complete reference use [Grub 2 User Manua](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html) where you can hopefully figure out how to mount the drive and then use "rn" to rename the directory. Good luck.

Comment: If you want to experiment with Linux, install VirtualBox and create a VM with the Linux version you want and use that for your experiments. This way your main system remains unaffected. If you make the VM read-only, your changes will be undone when you restart the VM.